# Need help with $\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(1+x)}{\left(1+x^2\right)\,\left(1+x^3\right)}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

I need you help with this integral:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(1+x)}{\left(1+x^2\right)\,\left(1+x^3\right)}dx.$$
*Mathematica* says it does not converge, which is apparently false.

Comment: Surely
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(1+x)}{(1+x^2)(1+x^3)} \leq \int_0^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^3)} < +\infty...
$$

Comment: I don't see any poles and plotting the integrand would imply the integral converges; in fact it eventually decays quite rapidly. If you ask for the antiderivative you get logs and dilogs and you can plug in the limits (it will probably simplify too using dilog identities) I get 0.3075243884.

Comment: Maple finds it in a closed form. See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t50jbdnk9pm5rqb/integral.pdf) as an exported  pdf file.

Comment: The result given by _Maple_ can be simplified in _Mathematica_ to $\frac{G}{2}-\frac{37\pi^2}{864}+\frac{\pi\ln2}{8}$, where $G$ is [Catalan's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html).

Comment: I didn't try much because the so-called closed form is anachronistic.

Comment: @user64494: for the Nth time, if you don't want to play, then don't disparage the game.

Comment: $$I(n)=\int_0^\infty\frac{(1+x)^n}{(1+x^2)(1-x+x^2)}dx\quad\iff\quad \int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+x)}{(1+x^2)(1+x^3)}dx=I'(-1)$$

Comment: Լ.Ƭ.: I submitted a bug report to Wolfram for this one - it is an egregious bug in the code they need to know about.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Huge pain in the rump, but in the end, fairly straightforward.  First observe that

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{(1+x)}}{(1+x^2)(1+x^3)} &= \int_0^{1} dx \frac{\log{(1+x)}}{(1+x^2)(1+x^3)} + \int_1^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{(1+x)}}{(1+x^2)(1+x^3)}\\ &= \int_0^{1} dx \frac{\log{(1+x)}}{(1+x^2)(1+x^3)} + \int_0^{1} dx \, x^3 \frac{\log{(1+x)}-\log{x}}{(1+x^2)(1+x^3)}\\ &= \int_0^1 dx \frac{\log{(1+x)}}{1+x^2} - \int_0^1 dx \frac{x^3 \log{x}}{(1+x^2)(1+x^3)}\end{align} $$

The first integral may be evaluated by subbing $x=\tan{t}$:

$$\begin{align} \int_0^1 dx \frac{\log{(1+x)}}{1+x^2} &= \int_0^{\pi/4} dt \, \log{(1+\tan{t})}\\ &= \int_0^{\pi/4} dt \, \log{(\sin{t}+\cos{t})} - \int_0^{\pi/4} dt \, \log{(\cos{t})}\\ &= \int_0^{\pi/4} dt \, \log{(\sqrt{2} \cos{(t-\pi/4)})} - \int_0^{\pi/4} dt \, \log{(\cos{t})}\\ &= \frac{\pi}{8} \log{2} + \int_0^{\pi/4} dt \, \log{(\cos{(t-\pi/4)})} - \int_0^{\pi/4} dt \, \log{(\cos{t})}\\ &= \frac{\pi}{8} \log{2}\end{align}$$

The second integral is messy but still doable.  First, we may use partial fractions.  Then we will get a series of zeta-like sums.  Some of them we will immediately recognize.  To the rest, we may apply the residue theorem.

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 dx \frac{x^3 \log{x}}{(1+x^2)(1+x^3)} &= \frac12 \int_0^1 dx \left [\frac{1-x}{1+x^2} - \frac{1-x-x^2}{1+x^3} \right ] \log{x}\\ &= \frac12 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \int_0^1 dx \left (x^{2 k}-x^{2 k+1}-x^{3 k}+x^{3 k+1}+x^{3 k+2} \right ) \log{x}\\ &= -\frac12 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \left [ \frac1{(2 k+1)^2} - \frac1{(2 k+2)^2} - \frac1{(3 k+1)^2}\\ + \frac1{(3 k+2)^2}+\frac1{(3 k+3)^2}\right ] \\ &= \frac{5}{72} \frac{\pi^2}{12} - \frac12 G + \frac12 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \left [\frac1{(3 k+1)^2} - \frac1{(3 k+2)^2}\right ] \end{align} $$

where $G$ is [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).  As for the sum:

$$\begin{align} \frac12 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \left [\frac1{(3 k+1)^2} - \frac1{(3 k+2)^2}\right ] &= \frac14  \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^k \left [\frac1{(3 k+1)^2} - \frac1{(3 k+2)^2}\right ] \\ &= -\frac{\pi}{4} \frac1{3^2} \left [\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-1/3} \frac{\csc{\pi z}}{(z+1/3)^2} \\- \operatorname*{Res}_{z=-2/3} \frac{\csc{\pi z}}{(z+2/3)^2} \right ]\\ &= \frac{\pi^2}{36} \left [\frac{\cos{\pi/3}}{\sin^2{\pi/3}} - \frac{\cos{2 \pi/3}}{\sin^2{2 \pi/3}} \right ]\\ &= \frac{\pi^2}{27}\end{align} $$

Therefore

$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{x^3 \log{x}}{(1+x^2)(1+x^3)} = \frac{5 \pi^2}{864} - \frac12 G + \frac{\pi^2}{27} = \frac{37 \pi^2}{864} - \frac{G}{2}$$

and finally...

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{(1+x)}}{(1+x^2)(1+x^3)} = \frac{G}{2} + \frac{\pi}{8} \log{2} - \frac{37 \pi^2}{864} \approx 0.307524\cdots$$

Comment: I'm always very pleased to see your answers. Out of curiosity, is there a particular source of problems/techniques that you've picked up and liked, or is it a conglomeration from over the years?

Comment: @mixedmath: Thank you!  To answer your question...I'm not quite sure how to answer your question.  I simply have a set of techniques I am very comfortable with, especially residue theory.  The important thing is that the art of integration lies in finding a transformation from one form that looks unwieldy to another that fits in a particular bag of tricks.  Comfort with residue theory expands that bag of tricks enormously.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\left(1 + \tan\left(t\right)\right)\,{\rm d}t ={1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\left(1 + \tan\left(t\right)\right)\,{\rm d}t + {1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\left(2 \over 1 + \tan\left(t\right)\right)\,{\rm d}t={1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\left(2\right)\,{\rm d}t = {\pi \over 8}\,\ln\left(2\right)}$

Comment: @RonGordon $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{a}{\rm f}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d} x ={1 \over 2}\left[\int_{0}^{a}{\rm f}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d} x + \int_{0}^{a}{\rm f}\left(a - x\right)\,{\rm d} x\right]}$

Comment: @RonGordon $\displaystyle{1 + \tan\left({\pi \over 4} - \theta\right) = 1 + {1 - \tan\left(\theta\right) \over 1 + \tan\left(\theta\right)} = {2 \over 1 + \tan\left(\theta\right)}}$

Comment: @RonGordon If you don't mind, I would like to clarify something. Why is it justified to write $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{-\infty}=2\sum^\infty_{0}$ when the function isn't even? Thanks.

Comment: @Superabound: it's due to the form of the summand.  In other words, write out the terms of the sum and see how you can make the replacement.

Comment: @RonGordon I understand it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

We can use the parametric integral to evaluate the integral. Let
$$ I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+\alpha x)}{(1+x^2)(1+x^3)}dx. $$
Then it is easy to see
\begin{eqnarray*}
I'(\alpha)&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{(1+\alpha x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)}dx\\
&=&\pi\frac{(9+8\sqrt{3})\alpha^2+(8\sqrt{3}-9)}{(\alpha^2+1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)}-\frac{\alpha^3\ln\alpha}{(1+\alpha^2)(1-\alpha^3)}
\end{eqnarray*}
and hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
I(1)&=&\int_0^1I'(\alpha)d\alpha\\
&=&\pi\int_0^1\frac{(9+8\sqrt{3})\alpha^2+(8\sqrt{3}-9)}{(\alpha^2+1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)}d\alpha+\int_0^1\frac{\alpha^3\ln\alpha}{(1+\alpha^2)(1-\alpha^3)}d\alpha\\
&=&I_1+I_2.
\end{eqnarray*}
It is not hard to get 
$$ I_1=\frac{\pi(5\pi+54\ln 2)}{432}. $$
Note
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\alpha^3}{(1+\alpha^2)(1-\alpha^3)}
&=&-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1+\alpha}{1+\alpha^2}+\frac12\frac{1+\alpha-\alpha^2}{1-\alpha^3}
\end{eqnarray*}
and hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_2&=&\int_0^1\frac{\alpha^3\ln\alpha}{(1-\alpha)(\alpha^2+1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)}d\alpha\\
&=&-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{(1+\alpha)\ln\alpha}{1+\alpha^2}d\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{(1+\alpha-\alpha^2)\ln\alpha}{1-\alpha^3}d\alpha
\end{eqnarray*}
But
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1\frac{(1+\alpha)\ln\alpha}{1+\alpha^2}d\alpha&=&\int_0^1\frac{\ln\alpha}{1+\alpha^2}d\alpha+\int_0^1\frac{\alpha\ln\alpha}{1+\alpha^2}d\alpha\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1(-\alpha^2)^n\ln\alpha d\alpha+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1\alpha(-\alpha^2)^n\ln\alpha d\alpha\\
&=&-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{4(n+1)^2}=-G-\frac{\pi^2}{48}\\
\int_0^1\frac{(1+\alpha-\alpha^2)\ln\alpha}{1-\alpha^3}d\alpha
&=&\int_0^1\frac{\ln\alpha}{1-\alpha^3}d\alpha+\int_0^1\frac{\alpha\ln\alpha}{1-\alpha^3}d\alpha-\int_0^1\frac{\alpha^2\ln\alpha}{1-\alpha^3}d\alpha\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty\alpha^{3n}\ln\alpha d\alpha+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty\alpha^{3n+1}\ln\alpha d\alpha-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty\alpha^{3n+2}\ln\alpha d\alpha\\
&=&-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n+1)^2}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n+2)^2}+\frac{1}{9}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=&-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n+1)^2}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n+2)^2}-\frac{1}{9}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{2}{9}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=&-\frac{7\pi^2}{54}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Putting everything together, we have
$$ I(1)=\frac{G}{2}-\frac{37\pi}{864}+\frac{1}{8}\pi\ln 2. $$

Answer (score -2):

**Hint**

This would probably work. Let $u = \ln(1+x)$ then $du = \frac{dx}{1+x}$ and factor the bottom $1+x^3 = (1+x)(\ldots)$.

Comment: @nayrb i did not mean by parts, straight substition yields $u du$ divided by some exponentials.